# Definition of Connection

Tags: iis

Does anyone know what constitutes an official connection to a workstation? I have a reasonably small scale operation where I am using a WORKSTATION, not server, as a server. For the most part, it works fine, but there is a 10 connection limit and I was toying with some new functionality and ended up causing some problems as the 10 connection limit kept getting hit.

From trial and error, I am pretty sure using a web service on a workstation counts as a connection as would surfing web pages served by the workstation. What if I set-up a MySql database? Everytime a PC connects or replicates data from the MySql server, would THAT count as a connection? What about connecting to the PC via mapping a drive?

Comment: What type of connection is limited to 10 users?

Comment: @Chopper3 Non-server [Windows OSes](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314882) have an inbound connection limit.

Answer (score 0):

Connecting from a PC via mapping a drive definitely counts.  Terminal services connections and such also count.  Windows should be counting accesses using Windows security services.

Web services, and MySql connections should not count.